# ls SCVMM 2008 R2 supported on Server 2012?

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, scvmm

We currently have SCVMM 2008 R2 on a Server 2008 R2 PC.

We are looking to upgrade the server to Server 2012 (possibly R2). Is Server 2012/Server 2012 R2 a supported or compatible operating system to run SCVMM 2008 R2 on?

Basically, I need to find out whether or not can we install our existing licensed SCVMM 2008 R2 onto this server if we upgrade it, or if we would need to get a copy of SCVMM 2012/2012 R2?

Comment: I will agree its part licensing, however the core concern is a SW compatibility question

Comment: I've edited your question to just concern itself with the technical aspect of whether or not SCVMM will install and/or run on  Server 2012/2012 R2.  However, as someone who's been deploying both 2012 and 2012 R2 since they became available, I advise in the strongest possible terms that you not even consider upgrading to Server 2012.  Upgrade to Server 2012 R2, or not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Windows Server 2012 doesn't support SCVMM 2008 R2, it only supports SCVMM 2012 SP1.

Comment: Can you site a source pls?

Comment: Here it is 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764213.aspx

Comment: That doesn't explicitly state 2012 isn't supported. Probably because it hasn't been updated since 2010. This is probably the best I am going to get though :( I'd love to see it addressed directly by Microsoft